# Possible F# type inference limitation

Tags: f#, type-inference

I'm quite sure that I run into some kind of limitation, but I do not understand it:

```
type IRunner = 
    abstract member Run : (string -> 'a) -> 'a
type T() = 
    let run4 doFun = doFun "4"
    let run5 doFun = doFun "5"
    let parseInt s = System.Int32.Parse(s)
    let parseFloat s = System.Double.Parse(s)
    let doSomething () = 
        let i = parseInt |> run4
        let f = parseFloat |> run4
        f |> ignore

    // Make it more generic ->
    //let doSomething2 (runner:(string->'a)->'b) =
    let doSomething2 runner = 
        // Error on the following lines with both declarations
        let i = parseInt |> runner
        let f = parseFloat |> runner
        f |> ignore

    // Want to do something like
    let test () = 
        doSomething2 run4
        doSomething2 run5

    // Workaround
    let workaround (runner:IRunner) = 
        let run f = runner.Run f
        let i = parseInt |> run
        let f = parseFloat |> run
        f |> ignore
```

Can somebody bring some light over this? I did not find any related question, sorry if i duplicated something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, if `doSomething2` has type `((string->'a) -> 'b) -> unit`, then `'a` and `'b` are fixed during each invocation of `doSomething2`, which isn't what you want - in your case `'a` needs to treated as both `int` and `float` during a *single* invocation of `doSomething2`.

It seems like what you really want is more like: `doSomething2 : (forall 'a. (string -> 'a) -> 'a) -> unit`, but that kind of direct universal quantification doesn't exist in F#.  As you've discovered, the way to work around this is to use a type with a generic method.

And even if F# did support `forall` types, as I mentioned in a comment inference still wouldn't be possible.  Consider your `doSomething2` function - we know that `runner` needs to be able to take an input of type `string -> int` to some output type and an input of type `string -> float` to some (possibly different) output type.  Here are several different signatures for `doSomething2` that all meet this requirement:

1. `forall 'a. 'a -> 'a`
2. `forall 'a. (string -> 'a) -> 'a`
3. `forall 'a. 'a -> unit`

Note that none of these types is more general than the others, they are all incompatible.  In the first case, we could pass `id` to the function, in the second case, we could pass `run4` to it, and in the third case, we could pass `ignore` to it (but none of those functions is compatible with the other possible signatures!).

Comment: It's a bit sad that you feel like programming on a very high level and then someting like this is coming up.
I feel like it should be possible to take whatever "run4" is and make it to a parameter.

Comment: Some languages support universal qualifiers like my hypothetical definition of `doSomething2`, but I believe that type inference is undecidable in those languages - you need an explicit annotation to define such a function.