# FSharp: Type inference with generic

Tags: generics, f#, type-inference

I do not understand why the following code does not compile

```
module GenericsTest = 
    open System

    type Dog = {
        name:string
    }

    type Apple = {
        size:int
    }

    let get<'a> (id:string) =
        Activator.CreateInstance<'a>()

    let creatorInferred getAsParam = 
        let apple = {
            name = getAsParam "some-apple"
        }

        let dog = {
            size = getAsParam "some-dog"
        }
        (apple, dog)

    let creatorWithTypeAnnotation (getAsParam:string->'a) = 
        let apple = {
            name = getAsParam "some-apple"
        }

        let dog = {
            size = getAsParam "some-dog"
        }
        (apple, dog)
```

If you look at the 2 "creator..." function - both of them give the compile error..

> this expression was expected to have the type int... but here has the
>   type string

I can see that F# is infering the return type of the getAsParam method to be int, because it is the first one that it encounters. However, why does it not then decide to use a generic return type?

As you can see, i have tried to for the function signature in the creatorWithTypeAnnotation method - but this has no affect.

I'm stumped! How do i force this to recognise that the getAsParam function should return a generic?

Comment: basically when it sees the first (the `Apple`) the type-inference will specialize `getAsParam` into `string -> Apple`, so of course your second usage of it (for the `Dog`) must fail - you could even see it if you remove the part with the error - the compiler should warn you that it constrained `'a` into `Apple` - just try to think how you would write a function returning a real *generic* `'a` without cheating (reflection, defaults, ...)

Comment: but.. how do i force getAsParam to have a generic return type? Note - i can make this happen if one of my arguments to getAsParams is 'a ... but i dont want to do that

Comment: you can *cheat* your way into this if you use an interface instead of a function for `getAsParam`

Comment: just think of the `'a` in your `getAsParam` as an generic parameter to `createorWithAnnotation` - see why it will not can be two different things here? - so if you need two different results you have to use two different `getAsParam1` and `getAsParam2` arguments too

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547804/possible-f-type-inference-limitation/ for related commentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a quick F#-interactive session on what I meant with *cheat by using an interface* (it just have to be some sort of `member` - so it can be a method on a class too of course):

```
> type IParam = abstract getParam : string -> 'a;;                              

type IParam =
  interface
    abstract member getParam : string -> 'a
  end

> let createWith (p : IParam) : int*bool = (p.getParam "a", p.getParam "b");;            

val createWith : p:IParam -> int * bool

> let test = { new IParam with member __.getParam s = Unchecked.defaultof<_> };;

val test : IParam

> createWith test;;                                                             
val it : int * bool = (0, false)
```

you might find it not exactly easy to implement some *saner* instances of `IParam` though ;)

Comment: Thanks... i understand the solution. But it doesnt make sense to me why it should work as a member and not as a func declare in the module root.... i realise my example didnt do this. Why is a member fun tion different?

Comment: @MikeS : It's about the type of the actual _value_ you have, namely `getParam` – it needs to be a _single_, concrete type per invocation of a given `creator` function. In your code, it must be _either_ `string->int` _or_ `string->string` at runtime, it cannot change types halfway through the function. With an interface, `getParam` is _always_ type `IParam`, and its `getParam` method can be invoked with any number of different types during a single instantiation of `creator`.

Answer (score 1):

As Carsten implies, the type variables are all resolved at compile time.  If you define `getAsParam` as `string -> 'a`, that doesn't stop the `'a` from being resolved at compile time.  Because it cannot resolve at compile time to two different types, compilation fails.

Consider your example:

```
let creatorWithTypeAnnotation (getAsParam:string->'a) = 
    let apple = {
        name = getAsParam "some-apple"
    }

    let dog = {
        size = getAsParam "some-dog"
    }
```

This could also be declared thus (I'll use `'A` instead of `'a`, since the intended convention is that lower-case type variables are for compiler-inferred types):

```
let creatorWithTypeAnnotation<'A> (getAsParam:string->'A) = 
    let apple = {
        name = getAsParam "some-apple"
    }

    let dog = {
        size = getAsParam "some-dog"
    }
```

Now it should be clear why the code does not compile.

Comment: So, i understand now why it doesnt compile. But can i not just do something like getAsParam<Apple> "some-apple" ... to force the method to be generic?

Comment: @MikeS no, because `getAsParam` is not a method. It is an argument--a variable--that happens to have a function type. The argument itself cannot have type parameters; that is, it cannot be independently generic. Rather, the type parameters pertain to the function being defined, namely, `creatorWithTypeAnnotation`. It's rather like in C#, where you cannot pass a generic delegate as an argument to a method. You have to provide a type argument at compile time. That type could be a generic parameter of the method being called, which is analogous to the requirement that `getAsParam` be generic.